# Disable the dictionary suggestion, backspace and delete word or sentence in EditText

Tags: android, xml

Update: Solved.
I am using EditText as Label display.
I added these lines in XML, but no change.

```
android:cursorVisible="false"

android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"

android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

In code side, added this line:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

I tried all of those settings, none of theme helped, also used all of them together still does not work.

What is the appropriate way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want to disable EditText completely or can you add words but prevent them from being deleted? Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag in your xml will fix suggestion problem:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine"
```

but for backspace or delete problem you can use addTextChangedListener like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // here you can check the changes and revert change or anything you like
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

for more detail see the [official docs of TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)